Why is AIC useful for comparing GAMs? Only for prediction?
I have a follow-up question to this OP. I hope to understand the difference between comparing 2 models with AIC, and interpreting the summary output of the full model - specifically for GAMs. Gavin compared the 2 models below, and I know the variables were selected based on his prior knowledge of the area and subject matter. Also, all covariates appear in both models (so, no model/variable selection going on here).
From the summary output he points out that...
Approximate significance of smooth terms:
                                edf  Ref.df        F  p-value 

ti(ToD,LONGITUDE,LATITUDE)   42.805 171.000    0.880  < 2e-16 ***
ti(DoY,LONGITUDE,LATITUDE)   83.277 240.000    1.225  < 2e-16 ***
ti(YEAR,LONGITUDE,LATITUDE)  84.862 329.000    1.101  < 2e-16 ***


some of the spatial ti() terms explain only small amounts of variation
in the data, as indicated by the F-statistic; there's a lot of data
here so even small effect sizes may be statistically significant but
uninteresting.

My question is, if my goal were to make inferential statements about these 3 interaction terms from the full model, would the F-statistic and p-value tell me everything I need, or would using AIC also be useful here? Could I make inferential statements since the same covariates appear in both models, or is that still post-selection inference?
Models compared:
# fit using BAM
m <- bam(MEASUREMENT ~
             s(ToD, k = 10) +
             s(DoY, k = 12, bs = "cc") +
             s(YEAR, k = 30) +
             s(LONGITUDE, LATITUDE, k = 100, bs = "ds", m = c(1, 0.5)) +
             ti(DoY, YEAR, bs = c("cc", "tp"), k = c(12, 15)) +
             ti(LONGITUDE, LATITUDE, ToD, d = c(2,1), bs = c("ds","tp"),
                m = list(c(1, 0.5), NA), k = c(20, 10)) +
             ti(LONGITUDE, LATITUDE, DoY, d = c(2,1), bs = c("ds","cc"),
                m = list(c(1, 0.5), NA), k = c(25, 12)) +
             ti(LONGITUDE, LATITUDE, YEAR, d = c(2,1), bs = c("ds","tp"),
                m = list(c(1, 0.5), NA), k = c(25, 15)),
         data = galveston,
         method = "fREML",
         knots = knots,
         nthreads = c(4, 4),
         discrete = TRUE)

## fit the simpler model
m_sub <- bam(MEASUREMENT ~
             s(ToD, k = 10) +
             s(DoY, k = 12, bs = "cc") +
             s(YEAR, k = 30) +
             s(LONGITUDE, LATITUDE, k = 100, bs = "ds", m = c(1, 0.5)) +
             ti(DoY, YEAR, bs = c("cc", "tp"), k = c(12, 15)),
         data = galveston,
         method = "fREML",
         knots = knots,
         nthreads = c(4, 4),
         discrete = TRUE)

# comapre fits
AIC(m, m_sub)

AIC is used a lot in my field, and I wish to learn what I can conclude about a covariate/model after it's been implemented. I understood that we could NOT make any inferential statements about a model after using AIC, but maybe I'm wrong when it comes to GAMs. I can't tell from Gavin's answer if his aim was prediction or inference (looks like inference).

I realise you emailed me about this the other week Nate; sorry I didn't get round to replying yet as I have been just finishing off undergraduate teaching for the semester and trying to clear the decks before I take most of the rest of December off.

@GavinSimpson Not a problem at all. Sorry to catch you at a busy time! I just opened up my question to the community thinking it might not be specific to GAMs, but wasn't sure. Thank you for helping me think it through, hope you have a good holiday break!

If you are really worried about it, then fitting m above should suffice if you had an a priori hypothesis or idea that the response varied spatio-temporally at all three temporal scales. You could interpret the estimates of that model and use the p values and credible intervals to do your inference given this model. You will be paying the price of hypothesising that such complex spatio-temporal features are a good way to explain the response through inflated standard errors on model terms.
It's hard to recall exactly what I was thinking when I wrote that answer; thinking back I might just have been using AIC to show in a gross way how much better then full spatio-temporal model was over a much simpler model (something the OP assumed would be too much to ask of a question on CrossValidated). I also wouldn't take an answer on CrossValidated as being something one should follow 100% accurately in a given situation - I don't know what the OP wanted to do with such a model; was inference their goal, was it prediction, forecasting?
And regardless, that one look at the AIC of the two models will make the p value a bit anti-conservative, but even if it made the p too optimistic by several orders of magnitude, it wouldn't change the result of any inference I did on those tensor product interaction smooths, nor their estimated value and effect size.
In this example, if the question was does the temperature of Galveston Bay vary spatiotemporally, using either the AIC comparison or the summary() p values would lead you to the same conclusion that, yes, temperature does vary spatiotemporally in the bay. The difference in magnitudes of the two AICs is on the order of 600 units, which is massive - the advice in ecology is often that if models differ by 20+ AIC units then there is strong support for the model with the lower of the two AICs.
What I think you should avoid - unless your aim is purely to find a model with good prediction error - is the kind of inference that involves fitting all combinations of predictors or a large suit a models, ranking them by AIC and then starting down the route of interpreting the p values as if you only fitted the final, selected model.
In the case of the example you linked to, I could just as easily have added select = TRUE to the model call and had the penalties do selection for me, rather than fit both models and compare with AIC.
You also need to be aware that using AIC to include/exclude a term is just doing selection via p values, you're just doing it through the back door. The common wisdom is that if two models differ by 2 AIC units, the simplest model is favoured and if you followed that mantra, you would be choosing to include or exclude the model term by which the two models differ using a p value with an $\alpha \approx 0.16$ (significance threshold):
> pchisq(2, 1, lower.tail = FALSE)
[1] 0.1572992

So, all you are doing if using AIC to do selection is just translating the p value to some new language and making a decision based on this translated p value. Hence, all the same issue of biased estimates of selected effects persist.
Until we get a good theory of post-selection inference for penalized likelihood models, I would just fit the full model your scientific hypothesis and data allows - i.e. just m in this example - and be done with it. Then you can interpret p values and credible intervals with the usual caveats that they rely on asymptotic behaviour and in the case of the p values for smooths, don't really account for the fact that we didn't know the values of the smoothing parameters.
If you're interested in prediction only, basically do what you want if the criterion of interest is RMSEP. If it's something else, like a probabilistic prediction/forecast, I would probably be a little more careful.
And if it really matters and you are worried about things like this, fit a few well-chosen models and then present all the models in your results. That way you are being honest about any selection you ultimately do to choose among the models.
None of the above is particular to GAMs.

Awesome! Thanks again for the very thorough answer!
